# L^p space question

Tags: functional-analysis

I am just wondering whether following is true?

Let $p>1$ If $f_n\to f$ in $L^p(\mu)$, is it then true that $f^p\to f^p$ in $L^1(\mu)$?

This is true if $||x|^p-|y|^p|\le |x-y|^p$. I know this is true for $p=1$. Is the inequality true for $p>1$?

Comment: $|x|^p=\Big( \sum_{i=1}{\vert x_i\vert}^{p}\Big)^{1/p} $ ?

Comment: @Razieh Noori: Yes.

Comment: @Razieh Noori: Sorry, $|x|^p$ doesn't mean norm. It's just the $p$th power of the scalar $|x|$.

Comment: It is ok, dear :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not true since $$2\leq \left(u+\frac{1}{u}\right)^2 -u^2 $$

Answer (score -1):

$||x|^p-|y|^p|\le |x-y|^p$ is just a result of Triangle inequality.  for first you need only wright definision $

$|x+y|^p\leq |x|^p +|y|^p $ for every $x$ and $y$. now replace $y$ with $y-x$
$$|x+y-x|^p\leq |x|^p+|x-y|^p ‎\Rightarrow‎ |y|^p\leq |x|^p+|x-y|^p$$ hence
$$|y|^p - |x|^p\leq |x-y|^p.$$
this time replace $x$ with $x-y$ and then you will have 
$$-(|y|^p - |x|^p)‎ =|x|^p - |y|^p\leq |x-y|^p.$$
 Now use the fact that if $-a\leq b\leq a$ then $|b|\leq |a|$.

For first part try to wright if you had problem just say.

Comment: ? triangle inequality for $\ell_p$ spaces

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space

Comment: No. $|x+y|^p \le |x|^p+|y|^p$ isn't correct. Take for example, $ x=1,y=1$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. $|x|^p$ does not mean norm.

Comment: then $|1+1|^p= (2^p)^\dfrac{1}{p}=2\leq (1^p)^\dfrac{1}{p}+(1^p)^\dfrac{1}{p}=1+1=2$

Comment: I first asked you what is $|x|^p$, didnot I?